# C++ Memory Leak - What do I delete, and where?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

A memory leak exists in the following function. The trouble I am having is knowing how, when, where, and what to delete. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void someFunc(double** ppDoubleArray, int length)
{
    double* pNewDoubleArray = new double[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        pNewDoubleArray[i] = 3 * i + 2;
    }

    *ppDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray;
}
int main()
{
    double dbls[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double* pArray = dbls;

    int length = sizeof dbls / sizeof dbls[0];

    std::cout << "Before..." << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pArray[i] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    someFunc(&pArray, length);

    std::cout << "After..." << std::endl;

    //Expected series is: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pArray[i] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    while(true){ }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I tried what to delete the new array I allocated after I had used it. It actually makes sense that this didn't work, but I am not sure what to do here..

Added `delete[] pArray`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void someFunc(double** ppDoubleArray, int length)
{
    double* pNewDoubleArray = new double[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        pNewDoubleArray[i] = 3 * i + 2;
    }

    *ppDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray;
}
int main()
{
    double dbls[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double* pArray = dbls;

    int length = sizeof dbls / sizeof dbls[0];

    std::cout << "Before..." << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pArray[i] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    someFunc(&pArray, length);

    std::cout << "After..." << std::endl;

    //Expected series is: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pArray[i] << ", ";
    }

    delete[] pArray;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    while(true){ }

    return 0;
}
```

Does this solve any, if at all memory leaks in this situation?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Keep your sanity. End world hunger.

Comment: I come from a C# background so using managed memory is definitely wonderful. I am really doing this to make sure I understand the ins and outs of memory management in C++.

Comment: This isn't C++ memory management, it is C memory management. C++ handles memory by storing stuff in container objects that take care of the memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are allocating & deleting an array in the function. And you are also returning it.

```
int main()
{
```

// This one is allocated on the stack, so it will be deleted when exiting main()

```
    double dbls[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    double* pArray = dbls;

    //...
```

// Your function allocates some memory now pointed at by pArray

```
    someFunc(&pArray, length);

    std::cout << "After..." << std::endl;

    //Expected series is: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pArray[i] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    while(true){ }
```

// Your forgot to delete the memory allocated by your function!!! Memory leak!!!

```
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
*ppDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray;
delete[] pNewDoubleArray;
```

You delete the array that you just passed back to the caller. Don't do that delete! It is up to the caller to manage the memory after you pass it back.

Rather than jump through all these hoops, you should consider writing "real" C++ code, using container objects like `std::vector` which will manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to do this:

```
void someFunc(double** ppDoubleArray, int length)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *ppDoubleArray[i] = 3 * i + 2;
    }

}
```

I don't understand why you'd allocate a new array if your intent is to modify the one passed in.

Comment: Normally you probably wouldn't, but doing so presents an interesting problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

In `someFunc` you allocate array, then set pointer passed by the user, to point to it. Upon exiting the function, you delete that array and user ends-up with a pointer to freed memory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `delete` `pNewDoubleArray`, as you store its address in `ppDoubleArray`. You have to `delete[] pArray`, when it is not used anymore or before setting it to another address (when calling `someFunc(&pArray, ...)` again).